# How can you know the sequence/names of the bands of a GeoTIFF/TIFF file in Java?

Tags: java, tiff, geotools, geotiff, satellite-image

I want to know the sequence of the bands (4 and more) of a GeoTIFF file for example whether the sequence is blue, green, red, near infra red, temperature, etc or green, blue, ...

How can I know that in Java, for example in GeoTools library? And by the way, are there specific tags in the GeoTIFF that indicates that (like TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION) or it is up to the image reader software to interpret the bands (even if it assumes the sequence mistakenly and considers blue instead of red and so forth).

Comment: Note: you can create a Tiff file, using qgis software for example, with different sequences of the bands, but in Java it will always read it R then G then B in case of 3 bands(regardless of what actually they are), then alpha in case of 4 bands, and band1 band2 band3,... band n in case of more than 4 bands. However  in BufferedImage class you can specify the BufferedImage type  like TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR, TYPE_INT_ARGB, etc. Does it mean that qgis is not giving a type to the bands or it means even if you give a type so the sequence will not be recognised in code.

Answer (score 0):

As I concluded, you can't know because you may create a band that doesn't have any meaning, also you can create any number of bands. Therefore, there are no standard names for the bands and there is no way to track the bands' names or sequence, rather it is up to the image reader software to interpret.